# Javascript Array Not Working within Another Function (No error reported)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

My array would not work as expected when items are added within a *Firebase* function.
However, it works outside of the *Firebase* function.

test() is the function called to add a "sample" string into *myList* Array.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Firebase scripts
...

var myList = [];

// Firebase storage function. There are 6 items in res.items. Expected myList.length = 6.
res.items.forEach(function (itemRef, index) {
    itemRef.getMetadata().then(function (metadata) {
        test();
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
});


function test(){
    myList.push("sample");
}
console.log(Array.isArray(myList)); // Returned *true* as expected.
test();
test();
console.log(myList.length); // Returned 2 instead of 8 (2 + 6 items from *Firebase* function).
console.log(myList); // Returned the Array with 8 items.
console.log(myList.length); // Still returned 2 instead of 8 (2 + 6 items from *Firebase* function).

...
</script>
```

The weirdest part:
In browser DevTools, `console.log(myList.length);` returned 8 as expected. No error is reported in the console. Please view screenshots for better understanding.

Thank you very much.

[Firefox Developer Tools screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUhXd.png)

[Chrome DevTools screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4Ymx.png)

Comment: This is because `itemRef.getMetadata()` is asynchronous and your `console.log` is executing before the data is obtained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `itemRef.getMetadata()` is asynchronous and your console.log is executing before the data is obtained. You may want to use an asynchronous function and await.

```
(async ()=>{
    var myList = [];
    for(const itemRef of items){
      const data = await itemRef.getMetadata();
      test();
    }
    //log...
})();
```

Alternatively, perform logging in the `.then` callback:

```
itemRef.getMetadata().then(function (metadata) {
    test();
    console.log(myList.length);
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.I have added a new line of code at the last line that prints the Array length in the console and updated all screenshots. It printed 2 although the previous line printed 8 items. Please view the screenshots again. Sorry for the inconvenience. Thank you.

Comment: kindly reload my question ;)
it's just an addition of code at the last line to show the weird behaviour. Thanks.

Comment: @ReganHung Did you add logging inside the `.then` callback?

Comment: Try `itemRef.getMetadata().then(function (metadata) {test(); console.log(myList.length)})`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. You are right, asynchronous caused the issue. I did not realise it due to the weird console log behaviour as shown in the screenshots. Console somehow managed to print all 8 items faster than my last line of code.

Comment: @ReganHung Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the promise inside forEach, try this one:

```
res.items.forEach(async (itemRef, index) => {
    try {
        let metadata = await itemRef.getMetadata()
        if (metadata) {
            test();
        }
        else {
            console.log('error');
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
});
```